# Twitter API & DotNetOpenAuth & HttpClient: Error "Could not authenticate you"

Tags: c#, twitter, dotnetopenauth, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to post a Twitter status update and I just can't get it working.

```
var consumer = new TwitterConsumer(); // WebConsumer implementation
var httpClient = new HttpClient(consumer.CreateAuthorizingHandler("THE_TOKEN", new HttpClientHandler()));

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
{
     {"status", "test"}
});

// yes, yes, ugly code, only testing here
var s = httpClient.PostAsync("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json", content);
var t = s.Result;
var u = t.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; // HTTP 401, response from Twitter is {"errors":[{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}]}
```

Of course, initially I thought there were some problems with my auth tokens or the OAuth process, but all other things are working fine:

The OAuth authentication seems to work, because I can access other API methods like `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/settings.json`.

**I can even post status updates when submitting the `status` via the URI**, like `POST https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=test`. I only get the error when I try to put the `status` in the request body.

According to Google a lot of people have similar problems, unfortunately the suggested solutions (like double-checking the url-encoding or the `content`-Request-Header) do not work for me (the request looks as it should in Fiddler).

Comment: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json accepts POST method only, so I am not sure you can submit status updates via GET method.

Comment: Compare the HTTP "Authorization" request header from account/settings.json API method with the "Authorization" HTTP request header from statuses/update.json and check for "oauth_consumer_key", "oauth_signature_method", "oauth_nonce", "oauth_token", "oauth_signature", check the Content-Type header too, this may helps you finding the problem.

Comment: vzamanillo, GET method definitely works.

I don't think that my problem is with the OAuth authentication, because every other method I tried on the API works fine. Just not the posting of a new status.

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update, if you try to use GET you will receive an error. What api version are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong :( I double-checked, and indeed I used a POST request, but added the `status` parameter to the URL instead of to the body. So I used a POST request, but a GET parameter - I'll update my question accordingly. Apologies for the mix-up.

Comment: Then look at my first comment and check headers and content type of the request.

Answer (score 2):

While not strictly speaking an answer to your question, this may solve your problem.

I suggest you to have a look on [linq2twitter](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/). It's a really nice C# api for Twitter.

You can either peek (it's open-source) on how they implemented signing requests to find a problem with your code or actually use it and not mess with creating/signing requests and parsing responses (used it on one of my past project, works fine, provides convenient api).

See [here](https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Updating%20Statuses&referringTitle=Making%20Status%20Queries%20and%20Calls) for example of posting status update and be sure to read [this docs section](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Securing%20Your%20Applications&referringTitle=Home) to understand how to properly configure auth (`TwitterContext`) in your scenario.

Hope this will help.